# How to match balanced curly brackets skipping escaped ones?

Tags: regex, perl, recursion

I'm trying to cook up a regular expression to match balanced curly brackets which takes into account, and skips over, **escaped** curly brackets.

The following regex is not working though. The script prints `{ def \}` instead of the expected output: `{ def \} hij \\\} klm }`. What am I doing wrong? How can I improve it?

```
my $str = 'abc { def \} hij \\\} klm } nop';

if ( $str =~ m/
              (
                \{
                  (?: \\\\
                  |   \\[\{\}]
                  |   [^\{\}]+
                  |   (?-1)
                  )*
                \}
              )
              /x
) { print $1, "\n" }
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to parse a context free grammar. It is inadvisable to do this using solely a regexp. I'd advise you to have a look at: http://perl-begin.org/uses/text-parsing/ (Look at the second section; "Advanced Parsing Techniques").

Comment: I'm trying to parse TeX input.

Comment: Yeah, a regexp will not do. Get yourself a parser generator from the link and use that instead. You may want to use a "proper" TeX parser, as well. Try http://search.cpan.org/~svenh/LaTeX-Parser-0.01/Parser.pm

Comment: @dsm LaTeX::Parser was last updated all the way back in 2000 and the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::Parser) say "This is a very early version of LaTeX::Parser, there are many bugs" and "Many bugs i'll find soon enough. Off the top of my head, I know backslashed brackes [sic] in LaTeX are considered normal brackets." The [only review](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/LaTeX-Parser) isn't very rosy, either. [LaTeX::TOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::TOM) got a poor review also, but has at least been worked on more recently. Not sure I would recommend either...

Comment: Yep. It seems to work just fine. Thanks. I'm just trying to find out whether the rather complex lookbehind addedum to your original solution gives rise to any unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex that will support any escaped symbols:

```
(?<=^|\\.|[^\\])({(?>\\.|[^{}]|(?1))*})
```

VERBOSE version with comments:

```
(?<=^|\\.|[^\\]) # Before `{` there is either start of string, escaped entity or not a \
(
   {            # Opening {
     (?>        # Start of atomic group
          \\.   # Any escaped symbol 
         |      
          [^{}] # any symbol but `{` and `}`
         | 
          (?1)  # Recurse the first subpattern
     )*         # repeat the atomic group 0 or more times
   }            # closing brace
)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY0lR9/3)

**UPDATE**

Since the above regex may match an escaped opening brace as first character, you may use

```
[^\\{}]*(?:\\.[\\{}]*)*(?<!\\)({(?>\\.|[^{}]|(?1))*})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY0lR9/4)

It will match all escaped and unnecessary substrings and capture into Group 1 only valid substrings.

Comment: It matches `abc { def \} hij \\\} klm \} nop` but shouldn't.

Comment: Why `(?>)` instead `(?:)`?

Comment: Atomic group can be used here [*to  improve performance*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#balanced)

Comment: @n.r. Also see the explanation in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3Epattern%29).

Comment: It looks like this fails to skip an escaped `{` when it is the first `{` encountered in the string.

Comment: @n.r.: Is the substring in braces single in the input, or do you expect unknown number of them? John and upvoters: this condition is missing in the OP.

Comment: Unknown number, unknown content. I'm trying to capture parameters to TeX control sequences.

Comment: Good, I updated the answer.  @JohnBollinger: please check the edit.

Comment: @stribizhev, "skips over escaped curly braces" does not seem to make any exceptions.  The test data do not exhibit an escaped `{` as the first `{` in the string, but the condition is there.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I accept the criticism, please check the updated regex. The issue is addressed using a lookbehind.

Comment: @stribizhev, that works for some, but not all cases.  For example, it  accepts the first `{` in `abc \\\{ foo def \} hij { blah } { blargle } \\\} klm }`, even though it is escaped.  I think you need a full-fledged non-capturing group, for you have to recognize and ignore indeterminate-length initial substrings.

Comment: @stribizhev, indeed so.  I have just commented on that there.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here -- the value of the string in `$str` and the regex pattern

Even within a single-quoted string, backslashes must be escaped when two appear together or when they appear as the last character in the string. A pair of backslashes is reduced to one, so the substring `\\\}` will generate `\\}` in the final string. To produce three backslashes followed by a closing brace, you need six backslashes in the code -- `\\\\\\}` (although five will do)

Your regex pattern is incorrect because the character class `[^{}]` will also match a single backslash, which will prevent it from being identified as part of an escaped brace sequence. So the alternative `[^{}\\]+` is matching `def \` from the string, leaving the `}` detached from its backslash

This program does what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $str = 'abc { def \} hij \\\\\\} klm } nop';

print $str, "\n";

if ( $str =~ m/
              (
                \{
                  (?:
                  [^{}\\]+  |
                  \\.       |
                  (?-1)
                  )*
                \}
              )
              /xs ) {

    print $1, "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
abc { def \} hij \\\} klm } nop
{ def \} hij \\\} klm }
```

Comment: I sometimes wish that perl had the equivalent of python's "raw strings".

Comment: @DanielMartin You can get close with a here-doc, but you have to `chomp` it, so not *quite* as handy.

Comment: @DanielMartin: Yes, it's a shortcoming of Perl 5. Perl 6 has `｢strings like this｣` where there are no special characters and everything is literal

Comment: This answer, too, fails to ignore an escaped `{` when it is the first `{` in the input.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I don't see what you mean. Please give an example input string. If I replace `abc` with `abc\{` in the sample data then my code correctly ignores it

Comment: @Borodon, no, it does not. given input `abc \{ def \} hij \\\} klm } nop`, your regex matches `{ def \} hij \\\} klm }`, even though the first brace is ecaped.  In fact, it should not match that particular input at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I don't see that. You have a different idea of *ignore* from mine. Perhaps you have the advantage of knowing TeX? I have corrected what the OP's code appeared to be attempting, which is to match everything from a bare opening brace to a bare closing one, treating escaped braces as ordinary characters and correctly nesting braces. Are you aware that `\{` and `\}` within a regex pattern match `{` and `}` respectively?

Comment: @Borodin, the behavior of your regex is demonstrably as I describe,  I tested it.  It handles escaping fine *except for* the first / outermost `{`, which can be matched as an opening bracket even when escaped, as in the example input I presented.  That fails to comply with the OP's express requirement the the regex "skips over escaped curly brackets" for the purpose of matching brackets.